# Hyper doc discrepancy with async in the call to make_service_fn

Tags: asynchronous, rust, hyper

I know async is new in rust, the [Hyper example](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/blob/master/examples/hello.rs) shows,

```
let make_svc = make_service_fn(|_conn| {
    async { Ok::<_, Infallible>(service_fn(hello)) }
});
```

But the [docs show,](https://hyper.rs/guides/server/hello-world/)

```
let make_svc = make_service_fn(|_conn| async {
    Ok::<_, Infallible>(service_fn(hello_world))
});
```

Is there a difference between these two constructs?

Answer (score 1):

This is the same code, just formatted differently. As `async` closures do not yet exist in Rust, both examples use a closure that returns an `async` block. In example #1, the block is started in a new line inside the closure, while in example 2, the block starts in the same line as the closure's argument list.